# Give a sub-rectangle, how does one divide the remainder of a rectangle into two parts such that the two new rectangles are more "squarish"?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

I have a rectangle R1, with width w1, height h1.

I am given a smaller rectangle R2 (w2,h2), whose origin is the same as R1 ie. (0,0).

How can I divide the remaining space into two rectangles, such that the difference between the length and width of each rectangle is as little as possible (more squarish)?

Here is what I have so far:
Given R2, there are four possibilities:

1. R2 is the same dimensions as R1, in which case there are no sub rectangles.
2. R2 is as wide as R1, but not as tall, in which case there is just one sub rectangle possible.
3. R2 is as tall as R1, but not as wide - again there is just one sub rectangle possible, just like in case(2).
4. R2 is not as tall, and not as wide as R1. In this case two sub rectangles are possible.

In case(4), there are two possible ways to partition the remaining space:

1. R3(w,h) = (w1-w2,h2) and R4(w,h) = (w1,h1-h2)
2. R3(w,h) = (w1-w2,h1) and R4(w,h) = (w2,h1-h2)

I figure that the ratio of the sides of a square is 1:1, so the smaller the ratio of the longer side to the shorter side, the closer to a square it is.

The problem is, there are TWO sub rectangles. So how do I decide which pair of rectangles is more square, since there are TWO of them ?

EDIT: If both R3 and R4's ratios in 1. are greater than in 2. , then obviously 2. is more square. But what if only one rect (example R3), has better ratios than in the other case, while the other rect (R4) has worse ratios ? Is that even possible ?

EDIT: Does it make sense to just sum the ratios of R3 and R4 in each case, and pick the case which has a smaller sum ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have an L shape, so we want to know whether to cut it vertically or horizontally to make the rectangles more "square". By "more square" we mean minimising perimeter. So the answer is simple. Make the shorter of the two cuts.

Comment: I'm struggling to wrap my head around this. Why is the perimeter less ? Shouldn't the ratio of the longer side to the shorter side be less ?